# Hide/Remove the site contents and site settings on user site (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: permissions, user-profile, my-site, site-settings

How can I remove or hide the setting (add an app, site content, site setting) from the user site <`MySite`>, but the user must have permission to edit his/her personal information?

Answer (score 1):

Go to site collections settings Permissions levels. This is a direct link to it `http://yoursite/_layouts/15/role.aspx`

There press "`Add a Permission Level`" and configure your custom permission level.

Then go to Users and Groups and create a new SP Group with permissions your created in first step. And add users to that group.

Comment: but this's for team site, i'am asking for the MySite (personal site)  trying to find any option to prevent this feature from all user so if any user login to his profile he can't do any thing except edit his personal information

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that. The mysites by default is created by user itself, that's why they have site owner permissions.

Comment: so, is there any option or what ...

Comment: Some options could be configured in Central Administration under User Profile Service Application: http://wellytonian.com/2012/10/restricting-permissions-on-mysites-sharepoint-2013/ . But in your case I suspect you could do that programatically only. Here is a related article, but for Moss2007, but maybe it helps you to get right directions http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2008/04/10/modifying-mysite-owner-security.aspx

Comment: if i delete the user profile service application , then i have to recreate it again in this case is there any option to do it  (i mean change the permission for the user ) ???

Answer (score 1):

For this,

you should change the PermissionsString attributes in MenuItemTemplate tags  in Master Page for the respective sections you mentioned,

**Example of Menu Item Template**

```
SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Settings"
```

**What attribute to Change**

```
PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
```

**Set it to**

```
PermissionsString="ManageWeb"
```

so only the users having Manage Web permission will be able to see the Menu Item.